# Definition of operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I want to show $T=d/dx$ is unbounded on $C^1[a,b]$ with $b>1$. Take a sequence $f(x)=x^n$, and $\|T\|=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}=\frac{\|n\cdot b^{n-1}\|}{\|b\|}$. I want to claim as $n$ goes to infinity, the operator norm goes to infinity, and hence it's unbounded. But the definition of operator norm only says I can take sup w.r.t. $x$, and I'm confused about why I can take sup w.r.t. $n$ here.

Comment: An alternate proof strategy might be to assume that $||T||$ is finite, then construct a function $f \in C^1[a,b]$ where $||Tf|| > ||T||\cdot ||f||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of operator norm does not compile: $Tx$ makes no sense for $x \in [a,b]$, as $T$ operates on functions. It should have been $$\sup_{f \in C^1([a,b])} \frac{\|Tf\|}{\|f\|} \geq \frac{\|Tf_n\|}{\|f_n\|} = nb^{n-2},$$
and thus $T$ is unbounded ($f_n(x) = x^n$).

Comment: a minor correction: $\frac{||Tf_n||}{||f_n||}=\frac{n^2+(b-1)n}{b(b+n)}$. Regardless $b$, it goes to infinity with $n$. So, $b$ can be any value, not only greater than 1.

Comment: @pabodu: What norm are you using on $C^1([a,b])$? I assumed the sup norm on both domain and image ($T$ takes $C^1([a,b])$ to $C^0([a,b])$). I must say however that I implicitly assumed that $|a| < |b|$, so most correct would have been to write $\frac{||Tf_n||}{||f_n||} \geq nb^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Pedro M., I expect $||f||_1$ in $C^1$ is $||f||_C+||f'||_C$. The operator $T$ is supposed to map functions from $C^1$ into itself. Definitely, its domain is narrower than $C^1$.